# Select element based on previous element of same type

Tags: css

I'm trying to select elements based on the class of a previous element of the same type.

For example, given the following HTML, select the third span element:

```
<div>
  <span class="red"></span>
  <span class="red"></span>
  <p>
    <span id="select me"></span>
  </p>
  <span id="don't select me"></span>
</div>
```

I want that span element to have the same properties as the previous span element because it has the class, "red."

Another way to say this: select an element with the class, "red," as well as the next element of the same type, regardless of class.

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around this.  Better than nothing would be a way to select the next sibling of the same type instead of just any following element.  For example, **span.red ~ span** would be okay if it didn't mean *"span element with ANY previous span sibling with a class red."*

Thanks for any help.

Here are more examples:

```
<div>
  <span class="red"></span>
  <span id="select me"></span>
  <p>
    <span class="red"></span>
  </p>
  <span id="select me"></span>
</div>
```

In the example above, the second span element is chosen because the first span has a class, "red."

The last span element is chosen because the third span has a class, "red."

```
<div>
  <span class="red"></span>
  <span class="red"></span>
  <p>
    <b></b>
  </p>
  <span id="select me"></span>
</div>
```

The main reason for this is that I have elements in an editable div. They are numbered with a css counter.  Some elements may be grouped together like a figure, i.e. 2a and 2b, while others are not, so I could end up with elements 1, 2a, 2b, 2c, 3, etc.  The class name I use just tells me that it's a "sub" element and to increment the sub counter but not the main element counter.  Not having a class for the next element after a bunch of sub elements tells me it's the last sub element and I should reset the sub counter.  The reason I have it set up this way is because I want to be able to move around the elements and have the numbering update automatically.  Also, it's easy to change whether something is a sub element just by toggling the class name.

Comment: Could you provide a second scenario for testing that would also satisfy your condition?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to have another case or two to test this with, but this seems to work for your example:

```
span.red ~* span {
    background: red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qbwY6/1/)**

Comment: This works for the given example, but not others that I've tried.  I'm going to add more examples.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to say "sibling of the same type" in a selector. But you can use the sibling selector following a selector of your choice, and combine these into a single selector that meets your needs, such as:

```
span.red + span, div.red + div
{

}
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that it's only selecting the immediate sibling, while the next "span" may not be the next sibling (see my updated post for more examples and further explanation)

Answer (score 0):

If it's only nested on level you could try this :

```
.red + * > span {
  color: red;
}
```

What is the use case for this? Why not just add red to all elements you want to be styled the same way?

Comment: See my edited post for an explanation of what I'm trying to do.  If I just make all the elements I want to be "sub" elements have the same class name, there's no way to know when the next set begins or ends.